# Angular - Keep values input fields whilst user logs in

Tags: angularjs

New to Angular - and I have a feeling this question more than likely already exists however I can't seem to find - so a duplicate question was not intended.

But.

I have a post button in my app, if the user is not logged in, on clicking post they are redirected the login page. After they login they are returned to the homepage however the fields they completed before they click Post are cleared. .

Can someone please point me to what Angular documentation I need to read to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set an object on $rootScope to contain the data so that it will not be lost between controllers and just map the fields from the view to the properties of the object you used in the $rootScope.

Please note that I'm not sure this is optimal or if it fits to any best practice.

I was assuming that by redirecting to a different page you mean that you are going to a different route which is handled by angular as part of the same SPA.

Comment: As in my comment below I use `$location.path('/login')`. I presume this is correct?

Comment: As long as that is a path is a part of you angular route config yes, you should be able to use the $rootScope as far as I know.